# How to calculate number in Group of an SSRS report?

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, fetchxml, server-side-rendering

In one of report that I need to develop using FetchXMl, I've to show number of male and female students that are studying a certain course. My goal is to show the reports as following:

```
Course Name      Male      Female
Physics           xx         xx

Chemistry         xx         xx

Computer Science  xx         xx
```

But I am getting

```
Course Name      Male     Female
Physics           xx
                            xx
                  xx
Chemistry         xx
                  xx
                  xx
                            xx
Computer Sciences xx          
                            xx
                            xx
                            xx
```

Any idea how to get specified format for this report?

Comment: Have you tried grouping by Course Name in your row group properties?

Comment: I would guess that your row group is also grouping on gender, remove that grouping from the ROW GROUP (not the column group)

Comment: @AlanSchofield: I've row group for courses only.

Answer (score 0):

Given a data table *students*:

```
id  course  gender
1   Math    m
2   Math    f
3   Physics f
4   Sports  m
5   Sports  f
6   Sports  f
```

You need a matrix (tablix) with a row group that groups by *Course Name* and a column group that groups by *Gender*. In the tablix body you add a *count* expression to show the number of students per course.

[design view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfOqx.png)

[result preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MLIAT.png)